# Algebraic Ideal and affine varieties equality

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $I=\langle x^2-y-4\rangle$ and $G= \langle x^2+y-4\rangle$ be two ideals in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

As obviously $V(I)=V(G)$, what can we conclude for $I$ and $G$? How they are related to each other?

Comment: It is not true that $I=G$. It is true that $V(I)\simeq V(G)$ as algebraic varieties, but they are not **equal**.

Comment: @FredrikMeyer ,My question can be generalized as : if two affine varieties are equal, what do they reveal of their corresponding ideals? Nothing?

Comment: If $V(I)=V(G)$ what can be said is that both have the same *radicals*, where radical of an ideal is defined as rad$\,(I)=\{f \mid f^m\in I$ for some positive  integer $m\}$.

Comment: This the famous Hilbert's Nullstellensatz

Answer (score 0):

In the example you provide the two varieties are merely isomorphic. Two affine varieties are isomorphic if and only if they have isomorphic coordinate rings $k[x_1, \dots , x_n]/I \cong k[x_1, \dots , x_m]/G$. Unfortunately, this tells us nothing substantial about the ideals $I,G$. In fact, we could have that $n \neq m$ and thus $I,G$ have different heights.

Comment: If $A$ is finitely generated domain then dim $A$ = dim $A / \mathfrak{p}$ + ht $\mathfrak{p}$ for a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p} \subseteq A$. If $n \neq m$ then the prime ideals must have different heights since their quotients have the same dimension.